# Erro em código JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sintaxe

Tenho um trecho de código que busca num Json o campo chamado `campo`, e o insere num array, que não pode ter valores repetidos. O meu array sempre retornava *undefined* e demorei para achar o erro. 
Por que o JS e até IDE consideram isso válido? Se `campo` é um array, então é **óbvio** que após o `.` iria chamar um método. No browser não houve nenhum erro.

Trecho de código errado:

```
while (i < listaContatos.length) {
   var dados = listaContatos[i].dados;
   for (var j = 0; j < dados.length; j++) {
       var nomeCampo = dados[j].campo;
       console.log(nomeCampo);
       if (campos.indexOf <= -1) {
           campos.push(nomeCampo);
         }
      }
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado com a sua outra pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77107/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa Nao entendi porque relacionado

Comment: Não é da mesma funcionalidade que você está desenvolvendo de lista de contatos?

Comment: Não estou dizendo que são duplicatas ou coisa assim, apenas estou dizendo que a outra pergunta tem alguma relação com esta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é considerado um erro por alguns motivos.

1. O ponto não indica que o método será chamado, pois para a chamada de uma função os parêntesis são obrigatórios. Do contrário você está apenas referenciando a função como uma variável. Isso o torna o código válido pois você está comparando uma variável do tipo `function` com uma variável do tipo `number` e o JavaScript não restringe isso devido à sua natureza fracamente tipada. Nesse caso, a comparação sempre retornará `false`
2. Segundo, se tratando de um array a notação de ponto pode ser usada para se referir aos índices do array.

Por exemplo:

```
var meuArray = [];
meuArray['asd'] = 4;
console.log(meuArray.asd); // 4
```

É perfeitamente possível sobrescrever o comportamento do `indexOf` e fazer aquele trecho de código funcionar de uma maneira interessante:

```
var meuArray = [];
meuArray['indexOf'] = -5;
console.log(meuArray.indexOf <= -1); // true
meuArray['indexOf'] = 5;
console.log(meuArray.indexOf <= -1); // false
```

Comment: Perfeito em variável do tipo function. Não sabia disso e como respondido na outra resposta, não achei na documentação que se trata de um atributo de array.

Comment: De certa forma toda função é uma variável.
Declarar assim:
function abcd() {}
é equivalente a declarar assim:
var abcd = function(){}

Comment: @fernandodelrio isso talvez seja verdade do ponto de vista de execução da função (parcialmente, vide [JavaScript Hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)), mas em um caso, você está criando uma função chamada `abcd` e, no outro caso, uma função anônima e atribuindo ela à variável `abcd`.

Comment: @gabrielhof tem razão, tem algumas diferenças mesmo

Answer (score 2):

```
campos.indexOf <= -1
```

Ao realizar essa comparação, você está comparando uma função ("campos.indexOf") com um inteiro "-1". A comparação é válida pois "indexOf" é um atributo do objeto Array, apesar de ser uma função, mas poderia ser um inteiro comoo atributo "length".

Comment: Sim, isso é o correto. A pergunta é por que Javascript permite que o errado seja executado e não emite nenhum alerta/erro

Comment: Entendi a real dúvida. Resposta editada.